# Mockito returning empty optional

Tags: java, spring, mockito, option-type

I am seeing a weird issue with my method returning an empty `Optional` in spite of mocking with `mockito`. What could be going wrong?

My test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(InfoController.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class InfoControllerTest 
{
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private Service service;

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

 @Test
 public void testDeleteValueSet() throws JsonProcessingException, Exception
 {
     DeleteValueSetContainer c1 = new DeleteValueSetContainer();
     c1.setValueSetIds(Collections.singletonList(1L));
    
     Mockito.when(service.deleteValueSet(Mockito.anyList(), 
              Mockito.anyBoolean(), Mockito.anyBoolean())).thenReturn(Optional.of(new Info()));
     mockMvc.perform(delete("/deleteValueSet").
             accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
             .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(c1))
           .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)).andExpect(status().isNoContent());
 }
}
```

Method under test:

```
@DeleteMapping("/deleteValueSet")
public ResponseEntity<Long> deleteValueSet(@RequestBody(required=true) DeleteValueSetContainer 
        deleteValueSetContainer)
{
    Optional<Info> optional = service.deleteValueSet(valueSetIds, 
            null, null);
    if(optional.isPresent())
    {
        Info valueInformation = optional.get();
        
        Long parentValueId = valueInformation.getParentValueId();
        if(parentValueId != null && parentValueId != 0L)
        {
            return ResponseEntity.created(ServletUriComponentsBuilder.
                    fromCurrentRequest().build().toUri())
                    .body((Long)valueInformation.getParentValueId());
        }
        return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
    }
    
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build();
}
```

I end up getting 500 error instead of 200 because the mock doesn't work as expected.

Method being mocked:

```
public Optional<Info> deleteValueSet(List<Long> ids, Boolean char, 
        Boolean digit)
{ 
   // Logic to populate Info
   Info i = new Info();  
   return Optional.of(information);
}
```

`Info` is a public static inner class in the service.

```
public static class Info
{
    private Long parentValueId;
    private Long id;
    private Map<Long, Long> idInfos;
 }
```

Comment: deleteValueSet() method has Long parameter. But you have specified List parameter in mockito. I think thats where the error is.

Comment: Sorry about that, I modified the method signature.

Comment: how about sharing your `service` initialization/mock in the test and

Comment: @Naman - I've `@MockBean private HelperService service` in my `Controller` test

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I've made some edits. I'm still not entirely clear on what minimal reproducible example involves in my case. There are spring dependencies needed to run this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry guys, this was on me. The issue was that the code under test was passing `null` for the booleans (I had incorrectly shown valid values in the code above) and `Mockito.anyBoolean()` doesn't accept `null`. Modifying it to `Mockito.anyNull()` did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You  should use anyLong() for the first parameter, not anyList().

Comment: Sorry about that, I modified the method signature.